# Using multiple cores for a loop that download .csv from different URLS

Tags: r, for-loop, web, parallel.foreach, cpu-cores

I have the following code that creates URLs for me which I need to download .csv file. I'm using loop since I have more than 300,000 different URLS:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df_vars)) {   urls <-
 paste0("https://dwr.state.co.us/Rest/GET/api/v2/analysisservices/callanalysisbywdid/?format=csv&adminNo=",
                     df_vars[i, "adminNumber"],"&endDate=01%2F01%2F2022&startDate=01%2F01%2F2012&wdid=0",df_vars[i,"wdid"])

 df_curtail <- read.csv(urls, skip =2) 

 df_null <- rbind(df_null,data.table(df_curtail)) }
```

This way takes 25 seconds for each "i" in the loop (each url) and will take a LONG time to download all the data. I'm trying to make the process faster by allocating multiple cores on this, any suggestion? I have tried the below code but haven't had any luck with it:

```
cores=detectCores()
 
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-2)
 
registerDoParallel(cl)
 
i=1
 
registerDoParallel(cl)
 
df_null <- foreach (i=1:2, .combine=rbind) %dopar% {    urls<- paste0("https://dwr.state.co.us/Rest/GET/api/v2/analysisservices/callanalysisbywdid/?format=csv&adminNo=",
 df_vars[i,"adminNumber"],"&endDate=01%2F01%2F2022&startDate=01%2F01%2F2012&wdid=0",df_vars[i,"wdid"])
 
  df_curtail <- read.csv(urls, skip=2)

print(i) 

 }
```

Comment: Whether this makes sense depends entirely on where the bottleneck is. Could be disk I/O, could be network bandwidth, in either case parallelizing across cores won't help you at all. (1) Can you tell us the dimensions (rows x cols) of the individual downloads (or a reasonable range)? (2) the successive `rbind()` calls in your first method are likely to be very bad (see chapter 2 of the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)).

Comment: The dimension of each individual download is (3650 x 23).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that you are being screwed by download bandwidth, but I will show some ways to start benchmarking your problem. I have done this all with a **local** file, which will give you some indication of intrinsic disk I/O and computational burden. You should try a similar procedure with a *small* subset of your URLs (say, 100 or 1000) to see what you can do to speed up the process.  If you are limited by download speed you **may** be able to help by distributing the problem across network access points ...

### simulated example

```r
dims <- c(3650,23)
dd <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(prod(dims)), nrow = dims[1]))
write.csv(dd, file = "tmp.csv", row.names = FALSE)
n <- 1000
```

### fully serial: read.csv()

```r
system.time(
    {
        pb <- txtProgressBar(max=n, style = 3)
        for (i in 1:n) {
            setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
            invisible(read.csv("tmp.csv"))
            
        }
        close(pb)
    }
)
```

This takes about 34 seconds. Maybe the bottleneck is in `read.csv()`?  There is a lot written about how to speed up file reading in R (e.g. [here](https://predictivehacks.com/the-fastest-way-to-read-and-write-file-in-r/)), although most of it focuses on reading *large* files (rather than reading *many* small-to-medium files): the general conclusions are

- if you can specify column data types in advance rather than making R guess that saves a lot of time
- `fread::data.table` > `readr::read_csv` > base-R `read.csv`
- (there is a *very* fast package called `vroom`, but it's not clear whether it will work in this context or not)

```r
library(readr)
system.time(
    {
        for (i in 1:n) {
            ## read_csv messes up progress bar somehow?
            invisible(read_csv("tmp.csv", show_col_types = FALSE))
        }
    }
)
```

Slightly to my surprise, this is slightly *slower* than `read.csv()` (40 seconds)

What if we specify column types?

```r
system.time(
    {
        for (i in 1:n) {
            invisible(read_csv("tmp.csv", col_types = "d"))
        }
    }
)
```

Doesn't help (still about 40 seconds).

On the other hand, `data.table::fread()` blazes:

```r
system.time(
    {
        for (i in 1:n) {
            invisible(data.table::fread("tmp.csv"))
        }
    }
)
```

3.6 seconds!

Now let's try in parallel (using the `furrr` package):

```r
library(furrr)
plan(multicore, workers = 24)
system.time(nrow(future_map_dfr(replicate(n, "tmp.csv"),
                         read_csv, col_types = "d")))
```

76 seconds total compute time, 10 seconds elapsed.

`fread` is so fast that parallelizing hardly buys us anything:

```r
system.time(nrow(future_map_dfr(replicate(n, "tmp.csv"),
                                data.table::fread)))
```

5.5 seconds total, 2.7 seconds elapsed.